# Format String Exploit, unexpected result

Tags: c, string, security, unix, exploit

I'm trying to implement simple example of Format String Vulnerability in C on 64-bits Linux. Here is my source code:

```
void not_called() {
    printf("Exploited\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // Buffer overflow vulnerability
    char buffer[256];
    gets(buffer);

    // User may input the format string
    printf(buffer);
}
```

I input the following string to program

```
AAAABBBB-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x
```

And the result is

```
AAAABBBB-8608002c-f458fe00-fbad2288-78252d78-252d7825-5e5c51a8-0-41414141-2d78252d-78252d78-252d7825-2d78252d
```

I can spot the AAAA as `41414141` but not the BBBB following as I would expect, as it's integral part of the same input string in the buffer.

Is this some sort of protection mechanism or am I misinterpreting something? My goal is to overwrite return address, and I need to read 8 bytes (AAAABBBB) as I'm working on 64-bits machine.

Pseudo-code for exploit string would look something like this

```
RETRNPTR%[decimal address of not_called - 8]u%[offset of RETRNPTR]$n
```

RETRNPTR is the address of memory storing the return address in the current stack frame.

So my biggest concern is, 8 bytes of RETRNPTR doesn't seem to be continuously in memory as I would expect. Second concern is, %n is int-pointer, meaning only 4 bytes are written. I'm also confused, where those values preceding the AAAA are coming from.

Comment: You are invoking undefined behaviour. Look at the disassembly to understand what exactly happens.

Comment: There is no function called `gets` in the C language. You need to update your C knowledge, `gets` was flagged as obsolete 17 years ago.

Comment: And what do you think `printf("AAAABBBB-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x")` with no variable list specified does?

Comment: That's why I'm using it. The fact, it copies the null characters which is essential, when working on 64-bits ROP. I assume printf without arguments will read the current values from the stack.

Comment: @TuomasToivonen No. The compiler will have printf go look for a `va_list` at some random part of your RAM. Anything might happen. If you are lucky, the program will crash and burn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're asking about code that has **undefined behaviour**; the behaviour of the code indeed should for the most of the part considered undefined by a casual C programmer.

Now, as to why you do not see `BBBB`. I presume it is because you're running this program on x86-64 system. There the calling convention is to do 64-bit pushes for the values that go on stack; However `%x` prints a 32-bit `int`; the 32 least significant bits of 64-bit stack value. To print 64-bit `long` values use `%lx`.

(Also, on System-V API for x86-64 the 6 first integer/pointer arguments do not go on stack at all; they're in `RDI`, `RSI`, `RDX`, `RCX`, `R8`, and `R9` registers).

For example I entered:

```
AAAABBBB %lx %lx %lx %lx %lx %lx %lx %lx %lx %lx
```

and got output

```
AAAABBBB 7f7c0a88f030 7f7c0a66b980 7f7c0a669980 7f7c0a88f031 786c2520786c2520 7ffc1456b6f8
100000000 4242424241414141 786c2520786c2520 786c2520786c2520
```

Comment: Also the first n arguments may be in registers and not on the stack.

Comment: So, is the case with format strings, that placeholder variables always aligns with the default word size (8 bytes on x86-64) and not the format type itself? %x reads the low 4 bytes from one word, and following %x will read low 4 bytes from the following word?